# CPack: How to use exporting to create library package? Missing *Targets-noconfig.cmake file

Tags: cmake, cpack

**Update**

It looks like it's Windows cpack version bug - under Linux (Ubuntu) the cpack command the missing file. I'll do more research and post results when I have more time.

---

Note: I completely changed this question because I was able to simplify it and create new, shorter example. Core problem, however didn't change in the slightest.

**Problem description**

I have a library project, let's call it Foo, which I pack using `cpack` command. This package contains `FooConfig.cmake` and `FooTargets.cmake` files (the second one exported by cmake mechanisms). Problem is, that this is **not enough** for cmake to use it. `find_package()` finds it, but when linking with `foo`, `No rule to make target foo-NOTFOUND', needed by bar.exe'.  Stop.` error appears.

But if I install it with `make install DESTDIR=./out_dir`, it works and it contains one more file: `FooTargets-noconfig.cmake`. This file contains path to the foo library file.

***So, what I need to do to fix this? Is there a document describing this behavior?***

Bonus question: I see that the `*-noconfig*` file contains path to the library, but not to headers directory. Is there a way how to configure library project so this generated file will contain it automatically, too?

**More info, notes:**

- My OS: Windows 7, 64 bit.
- Compiler: MinGW 4.4.0 (32 bit). (Note: yes, instead of `make` I use `mingw32-make` command.)
- CMake version: cmake 2.8.12.2.
- I tried to use result of the `make install` and the `No rule to make target xyz-NOTFOUND', needed by Index.exe'. Stop.` error disappeared, everything compiled and result exe was working as expected. It looks like the noconfig file is all what is needed.

**Workflow / reproduce steps:**

- After created the code (see bellow):
- `cmake-gui` to create build directory (library project) (Configure, then Generate)
- `mingw32-make` in build directory
- variant a) `mingw32-make install DESTDIR=./out_dir` to install the library
- variant b) `cpack -C CpackConfig.cmake -G ZIP` to get package with the library
- use files from previous step and move it to special directory which is in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` environment variable so the cmake can find it (note "move", not "copy" so the original files are removed).
- `cmake-gui` for executable project (again, Configure, then Generate)
- `mingw32-make` in build directory

Last step is different for variant a) and b). For a), build finishes and executable works normally, as expected. In case of b), error `No rule to make target xyz-NOTFOUND', needed by Index.exe'. Stop.` appears with no more information.

**My example code:**

```
- Foo/                          (Experimental library)
  - CMakeLists.txt              (XyzLib configuration)
  - foo.cpp                     (Function implementation - just prints something)
  - foo.h                       (Contains just single function)
  - FooConfig.cmake             (Configuration so the find_package find the
                                 library)
- Bar/                          (Testing executable)
  - CMakeLists.txt              (Executable configuration)
  - bar.cpp                     (Main function printing something and
                                 calling the Foo library function)
```

Foo/CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.3)
project("Foo")

add_library(foo STATIC foo.h foo.cpp)

set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER foo.h)

install(TARGETS foo EXPORT fooTargets
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include
        INCLUDES DESTINATION include)

install(FILES FooConfig.cmake DESTINATION lib/foo)

install(EXPORT fooTargets FILE "FooTargets.cmake" DESTINATION lib/foo)

include(CPack)
```

Foo/foo.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>

#include "foo.h"

void FooCall()
{
    ::std::cout << "Hello from Foo!" << ::std::endl;
}
```

Foo/foo.h :

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void FooCall();

#endif // FOO_H
```

Foo/FooConfig.cmake :

```
# - Config file for the Foo library package
# This module defines the following variables:
#  Foo_FOUND         - true if this module was found, false otherwise
#  Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS  - include directories
#  Foo_LIBRARIES     - libraries to link against

get_filename_component(SELF_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)

# Import targets
include("${SELF_DIR}/FooTargets.cmake")

# Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS
get_filename_component(Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS "${SELF_DIR}/../../include" ABSOLUTE)

# Foo_LIBRARIES
set(Foo_LIBRARIES foo)
```

Bar/CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.3)
project("Bar")

add_executable(bar bar.cpp)

find_package(Foo REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(bar ${Foo_LIBRARIES})
```

Bar/bar.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "foo.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ::std::cout << "Hello from bar!" << ::std::endl;
    FooCall();
    return 0;
}
```

**Some generated files:**

For case you're interested, there are few generated files:

lib/foo/FooTargets-noconfig.cmake

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file for configuration "".
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Import target "foo" for configuration ""
set_property(TARGET foo APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS NOCONFIG)
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES_NOCONFIG "CXX"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_NOCONFIG "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libfoo.a"
  )

list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS foo )
list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_foo "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libfoo.a" )

# Commands beyond this point should not need to know the version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
```

lib/foo/FooTargets.cmake

```
# Generated by CMake 2.8.12.2

if("${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}" LESS 2.5)
   message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake >= 2.6.0 required")
endif()
cmake_policy(PUSH)
cmake_policy(VERSION 2.6)
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file.
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Protect against multiple inclusion, which would fail when already imported targets are added once more.
set(_targetsDefined)
set(_targetsNotDefined)
set(_expectedTargets)
foreach(_expectedTarget foo)
  list(APPEND _expectedTargets ${_expectedTarget})
  if(NOT TARGET ${_expectedTarget})
    list(APPEND _targetsNotDefined ${_expectedTarget})
  endif()
  if(TARGET ${_expectedTarget})
    list(APPEND _targetsDefined ${_expectedTarget})
  endif()
endforeach()
if("${_targetsDefined}" STREQUAL "${_expectedTargets}")
  set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
  cmake_policy(POP)
  return()
endif()
if(NOT "${_targetsDefined}" STREQUAL "")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Some (but not all) targets in this export set were already defined.\nTargets Defined: ${_targetsDefined}\nTargets not yet defined: ${_targetsNotDefined}\n")
endif()
unset(_targetsDefined)
unset(_targetsNotDefined)
unset(_expectedTargets)


# Compute the installation prefix relative to this file.
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)

# Create imported target foo
add_library(foo STATIC IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
)

# Load information for each installed configuration.
get_filename_component(_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
file(GLOB CONFIG_FILES "${_DIR}/FooTargets-*.cmake")
foreach(f ${CONFIG_FILES})
  include(${f})
endforeach()

# Cleanup temporary variables.
set(_IMPORT_PREFIX)

# Loop over all imported files and verify that they actually exist
foreach(target ${_IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS} )
  foreach(file ${_IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_${target}} )
    if(NOT EXISTS "${file}" )
      message(FATAL_ERROR "The imported target \"${target}\" references the file
   \"${file}\"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}\"
but not all the files it references.
")
    endif()
  endforeach()
  unset(_IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_${target})
endforeach()
unset(_IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS)

# This file does not depend on other imported targets which have
# been exported from the same project but in a separate export set.

# Commands beyond this point should not need to know the version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
cmake_policy(POP)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the export command to create exported targets for use from the build directory:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages

CMake 2.8.12 does not support export(EXPORT), but does support export(TARGETS).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have no idea, how do you mean I should use it. I added `export(TARGETS foo FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo/FooTargets.cmake")` (copied and updated from the link you provided) and nothing changed - didn't help. AFAK, this will create `*Targets.cmake` file for build tree and if I would add the build directory to prefix variable, or if I would add `export(PACKAGE Foo)` line, it would work - but only locally. How should I use it to create files for portable packages? How should I use it so the targets file doesn't contain hard-coded absolute paths?

Comment: The result of export() is deliberately not portable. The CMake build directory is not portable. If you want portable, you use install(EXPORT) and you install. If you want to avoid installing, you might be able to do that, but you're on your own. You might have downvoted the answer because you don't like it, but it's not incorrect :).

Comment: Sorry if I offended you by downvoting - I did it, because popup text is "This answer is not useful" and your answer is not quite answering my question (Your answer is answer to "how can I make my build directory to able to be used in `find_package()` in local project" which is somehow different from the real one). But if what I'm asking for is not possible, just edit your answer, add "It's not possible, but you can do this:" to the beginning and I'll remove the down-vote - because that would be answer to my question although I wouldn't like it.

Comment: Anyway, about your last answer - if text in my question sounds like I want to make build directory or result of `export()` to be portable, then I apologize, it's misunderstanding. I don't. I want to make result of `cpack -G ZIP` portable with configuration files generated automatically (not hand-written) which I'm currently trying to achieve with `install(EXPORT fooTargets FILE "FooTargets.cmake" DESTINATION lib/foo)` (but I'm opened to other solutions) which is not working (see my main question for details).

Comment: Ok, sorry I think I didn't understand the question then and I don't know the answer, so I'll just leave my answer as-is.

Comment: Ok, np. In that case, I would like to ask you which part in my question is misleading or confusing so I could edit it and make more clear

Comment: thanks @steveire you answer helped me figure out how we can test our software in a staging area before installing it on the system. I used export(EXPORT ...) in order to install a `project_name-build-tree-targets.cmake` ... We can check for this file's existence and give it priority during testing in a staging area.